# Use of App::env() compared to getenv() since Craft 3.4.18

Tags: php, config

I've noticed since Craft 3.4.18 there is a `App::env()` function from `craft\helpers\App::env()`. This was created from the discussion here it seems: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/pull/5893

It seems `getenv()` can be problematic on multithreaded environments, which is why this change was made.

Should getenv() calls be replaced by `App::env()` in PHP code now, if using Craft 3.4.18 or above given the `App::env()` function will check `$_ENV` first then use `getenv()` as a fallback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

It’s not a requirement, but relying on `App::env()` is the current best practice and we’ve updated the Composer starter project to use it: https://github.com/craftcms/craft/blob/master/config/db.php

Comment: Thanks Matt, I did notice this, I saw it being used in db.php and app.php, thank you for clarifying.